# Terminal does not show in Kate

Tags: gnome, plugins, kate, konsole

I installed Kate in Ubuntu. But it is not showing Terminal in the application.

I read that I should install Konsole, as Kate is a KDE based application. I installed Konsole and ran Kate again but I didn't get the terminal. I even can't see Terminal option under view, tools view and tools.

What should I do to get Terminal in Kate in GNOME?

Comment: I wouldn't think this would be the case, but... maybe try complete uninstall of Kate, then re-install now that Konsole is there

Comment: You didn't say what Ubuntu version you were running, but I just tried the latest (15.04) Kubuntu LiveCD and found that, unlike previous versions where I don't think you could even disable the terminal plugin, in this one it's not enabled by default.  I went into Settings - Configure Kate - Plugins and enabled "Terminal tool view"; then it showed up.

Comment: For ubuntu 16.04 users, you need to do both: install konsole alongside kate (it doesn't come as dependance) and enable the plugin in kate configuration.

Answer (score 4):

Most probably you have it installed correctly but by default kate will not show it, you need to configure it:

Go to **Kate ⇒ Configure ⇒ Application ⇒ Plugins** and check the *Terminal tool view* checkbox. This will immediately change your kate window by showing the konsole , setup in the working directory in which kate was launched.

Answer (score 0):

I found that KDE Konsole was not installed. Once installed it worked.